# Running Karate Test as part of github actions CICD pipeline but using Karate as VSCODE extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, karate

If we install Karate as VSCODE extension, as there was no coding setup required when using the VSCODE extension(e.g. karate in not added in the maven dependencies as karate works already with the vscode extension installation thus in the github action workflow when adding the maven dependencies karate will not be included). Can we then run the Karate test scripts/features in the github actions CICD pipeline without it being part of the maven dependencies?

Appreciate if you may please give/share an example or link for reference.

Thanks,

Currently exploring Karate Framework and saw the availability of Karate as VSCODE extension hoping that using this extension will work in the github action CICD workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once you have developed and run tests locally using the VS Code extension, you can run the same tests in a CI / CD pipeline.

One way to do this is use the Standalone JAR: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Other-Runtime-Options

If you work with your DevOps folks, you should very quickly be able to figure out either a recipe to set up Karate. Many teams also use Docker.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, have read the given link and will give it a try and reply back once successful or if I encounter any issue.